# Is there anything wrong with this run_on_main() macro?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Objective-C Gurus,

I have been using the following macro to ensure that a block is run on a main thread.  The idea is simple:  if I am currently on the main thread, then I will run the block immediately.  If the current thread is not the main thread, then I queue the block to be run on the main thread asynchronously (so that it does not block the current thread).

Do you see any problems with this?  Is anything here unsafe, or causing errors that I am unaware of?  Is there a better way of doing this?

```
#define run_on_main(blk)    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) { blk(); } else { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), blk); }
```

Example Usage:

```
-(BOOL)loginCompletedSuccessfully
{
    NSLog(@"loginCompletedSuccessfully");
    //  This may be called from a network thread, so let's
    //  ensure the rest of this is running on the main thread.
    run_on_main(^{
        if (_appStartupType == AppLaunch) {
            self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:DEVICED(@"XPCStoryboard") bundle:nil];
            self.navigationController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        }
        [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    });
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `dispatch_async` to cover both cases? It seems odd in one case the block is executed immediately and in the other it will be run at some point very soon - your code can not reason about which it will be without checking which thread they are on first, which defeats the point of this? So I guess I'm trying to say the execution order is different depending on what thread you are on but the calling code does not know this

Comment: @Paul.s - The reason is simple:  If I am on the MainThread, then I care about execution order.  If I'm not on the main thread, then I simply want to put the block onto the main thread in the next available position without unintentionally causing a deadlock condition.  This is important when a method doesn't know if it is called due to UI events, or Network Responses on background threads.

Comment: your concern for deadlock would make sense if you was using `dispatch_sync` but your example uses `dispatch_async` which is a non blocking method

Comment: @Paul.s  I've continued this discussion on your answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has the potential for nasty subtle bugs with execution order.

Take this simple example (on the main thread)

```
__block NSInteger integer = 5;

run_on_main(^{
  integer += 10;
});

NSLog(@"From Main %d", integer);
```

This prints the result `15`

The same code ran in a background thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
  __block NSInteger integer = 5;

  run_on_main(^{
    integer += 10;
  });

  NSLog(@"From background %d", integer);
});
```

The result will be `5`... or `15` depending on race conditions between the threads.

This inconsistency may trip you up.

Why not just use `dispatch_async` in both cases and be safe in the knowledge that both will now exhibit the same behaviour. This is safe and fine because you are using `async` which is non blocking

Comment: In the second case the reault may as well be 15.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe sorry I don't follow?

Comment: In the second case the result depends on a race condition. If the main queue happens to increment `integer` before the background thread prints it, the result will be 15.

Comment: Indeed this is my point - the result is indeterminate. This inconsistency is hidden behind the interface the OP has created. I just put 5 as this was the result I got from running it a couple of times. I'll clarify in my answer

Comment: @Paul.s I put a response to your comment on the question (above).  However, consider the case where a method may be called from both a UI event and a Network Response or Background Thread.  When it is called from the Main Thread, it wants to ensure it is executed synchronously with the other Main Thread activities.  When it isn't called on the main thread, it doesn't care about the synchronous activities of its current background/network thread, it only cares that it be added to the main thread.  It also doesn't want to hold up the current thread with a possible deadlock.

Comment: @Paul.s BTW, Your answer concerning nasty bugs due to execution order is a valid response.  (+1 from me)

Comment: @JohnFowler my issue is the actual implementation and potential side effects are completely hidden from the caller so I'd be tempted to rename the method something like `run_synchronously_on_main_or_add_to_main_queue`, which of course makes me shudder and rethink my approach to the problem.

Comment: I'd agree that due to the inconsistent async/sync behavior, it would be better for readability to write out the if/else in your `loginCompletedSuccessfully` method. `run_on_main` looks very innocuous, and hides its inconsistent behavior from the reader, so if the kind of bug @Paul.s describes does occur, the person trying to fix it may gloss right over it.

Answer (score 4):

As always, if there is another option, avoid macros. In this case it's easy to use a function instead:

```
static inline void run_on_main(dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        block();
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to your macro definition; you can even put it in the same place. The advantage is that you get compiler support for syntax checks, Xcode syntax completion for the blocks (very useful), debugger support when debugging and lots more.

Plus: `run_on_main` does not appear brown in your source code ;)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll look at making that change...  This may really help with the debugger too, since the debugger sometimes can't find the right line.

Comment: Question:  I have my macro in a "Common.h" file that is included all over the place.  Is that the best place to put the static inline method you have defined?

Comment: @JohnFowler Yes, that's a perfect place to put a commonly used function. Since it's declared `static inline` there's no problem including it everywhere.